# Close vaadin session when the user close the browser page, how?

Tags: java, session, vaadin7

My problem is that when a user closes the browser page and reopens immediately it remains logged.

How can I close the Vaadin session when the 'user closes the browser page?

I have found this two methods but works only when the user press on logout:

```
detachListener = new DetachListener() {
        @Override
        public void detach(final DetachEvent detachEvent) {
            System.out.println("I am out!");
        }
    };
    addDetachListener(detachListener);
```

or

```
@Override
public void close(){
   System.out.println("I am out, from close!");
}
```

Have anyone an idea?

Vaadin version: 7.4.2

Comment: It is impossible from `HTTP` perspective. You can try to open `Websoket` connection from page and us it to check that page is open. But I have no idea how to implement it in `vaadin`

Comment: so I have to wait the expired session when the 'user closes the browser page...